# Different ng-body based on condition?

Tags: angularjs

What is the best way to have one outer page, with all of the needed script tags and layout, but then show a different body based on a condition (such a the user's logged in status or role)?

I'm currently following John Papa's "modular" and "cc-bmean" projects, and really like the way he is nesting layouts and controllers.  Unfortunately, he does not touch on authorization of any kind.

John Papa's ng-demos project on GitHub:

```
https://github.com/johnpapa/ng-demos
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand the question, but maybe you are looking for angular routing and multiple views? See Angular.js tutorial [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07). The behavior of each view based on the user's status can then be specified in the controller of the specific view.